# How to keep 2 decimal even if it's .00

Tags: python

I've been working on this assignment for one of my class and I can't figure out how to round to 2 decimal even if it's .00

I'm printing a table and it just look's weird here's my result :

```
             1           10000.0             600.0           10600.0
             2           10600.0             636.0           11236.0
             3           11236.0            674.16          11910.16
             4          11910.16            714.61          12624.77
             5          12624.77            757.49          13382.26
             6          13382.26            802.94          14185.19
             7          14185.19            851.11           15036.3
             8           15036.3            902.18          15938.48
             9          15938.48            956.31          16894.79
            10          16894.79           1013.69          17908.48
```

I print a list of item that I round to 1 for [0] and to 2 for the rest
(Sorry some of the var are in french XD)

```
for n in i_liste_l:
    if n == i_liste_l[0]:
        n = int(round(n,0))
        i_liste_l[0] = n
    else:
        index_i = int(i_liste_l.index(n))
        i_liste_l[index_i] = float(round(n,2))
i = i+1

print('{:>{width}}{:>{width}}{:>{width}}{:>{width}}'.format(*i_liste_l,width = indent))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of the question I'm-a filling in some of the values:

```
print('{:>{width}}{:>{width}}{:>{width}}{:>{width}}'.format(1.2, 1, 4.32, 65.3, width=7))
#>>>     1.2      1   4.32   65.3
```

You want the `.Nf` formatter:

```
print('{:>{width}.2f}{:>{width}.2f}{:>{width}.2f}{:>{width}.2f}'.format(1.2, 1, 4.32, 65.3, width=7))
#>>>    1.20   1.00   4.32  65.30
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thanks how can I find all those formatter ?

Comment: [In this odd section of the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
print('%5.2f' % 1.0)
```

to print

```
 1.00 # a space in front, 4 characters for the numbers, total 5
```

Comment: The `.format()` syntax is considered to be the way to go for string formatting now as its more precise and in depth.

Comment: Even if it wasn't, SKTLZ is *already* using `.format`. Why use another format type on top of that?

Comment: what is SKTLZ? can you explain more?

Comment: SKTLZ is the name of the OP (original poster).  It's a username.

Comment: haha, didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "%.2f"

Example -

```
>>> x = 10.0/2
>>> print x
5.0
>>> print "%.2f" % x
5.00
>>> x = 5.0/2
>>> print "%.2f" % x
2.50
```

Comment: The .format() syntax is considered to be the way to go for string formatting now as its more precise and in depth. Also, how is this different to the answer by @justhalf which was answered earlier?